# MySQL Query GROUP BY day / month / year

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, group-by

Is it possible to make a simple query to count how many records I have in a determined period of time like a year, month, or day, having a `TIMESTAMP` field, like:

```
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM stats
WHERE record_date.YEAR = 2009
GROUP BY record_date.YEAR
```

Or even:

```
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM stats
GROUP BY record_date.YEAR, record_date.MONTH
```

To have a monthly statistic.

Thanks!

Comment: I guess it's supposed to be `GROUP BY record_date.MONTH` in your first code snippet?

Answer (score 1229, accepted):

```
GROUP BY YEAR(record_date), MONTH(record_date)
```

Check out the [date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) in MySQL.

Comment: You may want to add an extra column for added clarity in some cases such as where records span several years.
SELECT COUNT(event_id), DATE_FORMAT(event_start, '%Y/%m')

Comment: Simple complete example:
`SELECT count(*), record_date FROM anytable WHERE anytable.anycolumn = 'anycondition' GROUP BY YEAR(record_date), month(record_date);` note: record_date is a date type TIMESTAMP

Comment: Probably worth mentioning this didn't run on my MySQL 5.7 with a COUNT aliased column (no error,  I got zero results). When I changed to select those fields with alias, I could then group by the alias. This is standard MySQL 5.7 docker image running in a local environment so I've no idea why it didn't error or return results.

Comment: Oh god, if I knew this earlier...so many lines of PHP to do something mysql can do in one line.

Answer (score 289):

```
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(record_date, '%Y%m')
```

---

***Note** (primarily, to potential downvoters). Presently, this may not be as efficient as other suggestions. Still, I leave it as an alternative, and a one, too, that can serve in seeing how faster other solutions are. (For you can't really tell fast from slow until you see the difference.) Also, as time goes on, changes could be made to MySQL's engine with regard to optimisation so as to make this solution, at some (perhaps, not so distant) point in future, to become quite comparable in efficiency with most others.*

Comment: I have a feeling that this would not perform well because a format function wouldn't be able to use an index on the date column.

Comment: @Stv: You might want to consider [@fu-chi's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7721169/297408) then. As far as I can tell, the grouping expressions in both that answer and mine evaluate to the same thing but `EXTRACT()` may be more efficient than `DATE_FORMAT()`. (I don't have a MySQL for proper testing, though.)

Comment: I like grouping by the date and time functions year, month, etc.  But I love using date_format in the select to reconstitute the date for the groups `date_format(concat(year(timestamp), "-", month(timestamp), "-", day(timestamp), " ", hour(timestamp), ":00"), '%Y-%m-%d')`

Answer (score 58):

try this one

```
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM stats
GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM record_date)
```

[EXTRACT(unit FROM date)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract) function is better as less grouping is used and the function return a number value.

Comparison condition when grouping will be faster than DATE_FORMAT function (which return a string value). Try using function|field that return non-string value for SQL comparison condition (WHERE, HAVING, ORDER BY, GROUP BY).

Answer (score 49):

I tried using the 'WHERE' statement above, I thought its correct since nobody corrected it but I was wrong; after some searches I found out that this is the right formula for the WHERE statement so the code becomes like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(id)  
FROM stats  
WHERE YEAR(record_date) = 2009  
GROUP BY MONTH(record_date)
```

Answer (score 41):

If your search is over several years, and you still want to group monthly, I suggest:

**version #1:**

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE YEAR(record_date), MONTH(record_date), COUNT(*)
FROM stats
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(record_date, '%Y%m')
```

**version #2** (more efficient)**:**

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE YEAR(record_date), MONTH(record_date), COUNT(*)
FROM stats
GROUP BY YEAR(record_date)*100 + MONTH(record_date)
```

I compared these versions on a big table with 1,357,918 rows ([innodb](/questions/tagged/innodb)),
and the 2nd version appears to have better results.

**version1** *(average of 10 executes)*:  1.404 seconds 
**version2** *(average of 10 executes)*:  0.780 seconds

(`SQL_NO_CACHE` key added to prevent MySQL from CACHING to queries.)

Comment: Consider including @fu-chi's suggestion into your tests, it may prove even more efficient. Also, you tested `GROUP BY YEAR(record_date)*100 + MONTH(record_date)`, but why not test `GROUP BY YEAR(record_date), MONTH(record_date)` as well?

Comment: If you use COUNT(1) insteed COUNT(*) it will be even faster, and result data are same.

Comment: What is that `*100` on the versión #2? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `*100` to `YEAR(record_date)*100 + MONTH(record_date) == DATE_FORMAT(record_date, '%Y%m')`

Answer (score 22):

You can do this simply Mysql [DATE_FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function in GROUP BY. You may want to add an extra column for added clarity in some cases such as where records span several years then same month occurs in different years.Here so many option you can customize this. Please read this befor starting. Hope it should be very helpful for you. Here is sample query for your understanding

```
SELECT
    COUNT(id),
    DATE_FORMAT(record_date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS DAY,
    DATE_FORMAT(record_date, '%Y-%m') AS MONTH,
    DATE_FORMAT(record_date, '%Y') AS YEAR

FROM
    stats
WHERE
    YEAR = 2009
GROUP BY
    DATE_FORMAT(record_date, '%Y-%m-%d ');
```

Comment: Great. Working well

Answer (score 20):

If you want to filter records for a particular year (e.g. 2000) then optimize the `WHERE` clause like this:

```
SELECT MONTH(date_column), COUNT(*)
FROM date_table
WHERE date_column >= '2000-01-01' AND date_column < '2001-01-01'
GROUP BY MONTH(date_column)
-- average 0.016 sec.
```

Instead of:

```
WHERE YEAR(date_column) = 2000
-- average 0.132 sec.
```

The results were generated against a table containing 300k rows and index on date column.

As for the `GROUP BY` clause, I tested the three variants against the above mentioned table; here are the results:

```
SELECT YEAR(date_column), MONTH(date_column), COUNT(*)
FROM date_table
GROUP BY YEAR(date_column), MONTH(date_column)
-- codelogic
-- average 0.250 sec.

SELECT YEAR(date_column), MONTH(date_column), COUNT(*)
FROM date_table
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date_column, '%Y%m')
-- Andriy M
-- average 0.468 sec.

SELECT YEAR(date_column), MONTH(date_column), COUNT(*)
FROM date_table
GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM date_column)
-- fu-chi
-- average 0.203 sec.
```

The last one is the winner.

Answer (score 18):

If you want to group by date in MySQL then use the code below:

```
 SELECT COUNT(id)
 FROM stats
 GROUP BY DAYOFMONTH(record_date)
```

Hope this saves some time for the ones who are going to find this thread.

Comment: It's important to note that you'd also need to group by `MONTH(record_date)` as well to account for multiple months.

Answer (score 13):

Complete and simple solution with similarly performing yet shorter and more flexible alternative currently active:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stats
-- GROUP BY YEAR(record_date), MONTH(record_date), DAYOFMONTH(record_date)
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(record_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want to get a monthly statistics with row counts per month of each year ordered by latest month, then try this:

```
SELECT count(id),
      YEAR(record_date),
      MONTH(record_date) 
FROM `table` 
GROUP BY YEAR(record_date),
        MONTH(record_date) 
ORDER BY YEAR(record_date) DESC,
        MONTH(record_date) DESC
```

Answer (score 5):

The following query worked for me in Oracle Database 12c Release 12.1.0.1.0

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM stats
GROUP BY 
extract(MONTH FROM TIMESTAMP),
extract(MONTH FROM TIMESTAMP),
extract(YEAR  FROM TIMESTAMP);
```

Answer (score 5):

try it

GROUP BY YEAR(record_date), MONTH(record_date)

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to optimize the one year group selection like so:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM stats
 WHERE record_date >= :year 
   AND record_date <  :year + INTERVAL 1 YEAR;
```

This way you can just bind the year in once, e.g. `'2009'`, with a named parameter and don't need to worry about adding `'-01-01'` or passing in `'2010'` separately.

Also, as presumably we are just counting rows and `id` is never `NULL`, I prefer `COUNT(*)` to `COUNT(id)`.

Answer (score 2):

(Roughly) benchmarking some of the solutions on a 2.5M row table, it would appear that `EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM date)` is the clear performance winner currently.

```
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%Y-%m')
2.4555 seconds

GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM `date`)
1.3241 seconds

GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(`date`)
1.8917 seconds

GROUP BY YEAR(date)*100 + MONTH(date)
1.7791 seconds

GROUP BY SUBSTRING(`date`,1,7)
2.2972 seconds

GROUP BY LEFT(`date`,7)
2.2346 seconds
```

It should be noted that none of these queries can make use of an index; therefore if you need better performance the simplest method is to add a VIRTUAL column (MySQL 5.7+) with an index:

```
ALTER TABLE `foobar`
ADD `date_year_month` MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED AS (EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM `date`)) VIRTUAL
AFTER `date`,
ADD INDEX (`date_year_month`);
```

```
GROUP BY `date_year_month`
0.0330 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one more approach.  This uses [MySQL's LAST_DAY() function][1] to map each timestamp to its month. It also is capable of filtering by year with an efficient range-scan if there's an index on `record_date`.

```
  SELECT LAST_DAY(record_date) month_ending, COUNT(*) record_count
    FROM stats
   WHERE record_date >= '2000-01-01'
     AND record_date <  '2000-01-01' + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
   GROUP BY LAST_DAY(record_date)
```

If you want your results by day, use `DATE(record_date)` instead.

If you want your results by calendar quarter, use `YEAR(record_date), QUARTER(record_date)`.

Here's a writeup. https://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/sql-reporting-time-intervals/
[1]: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to get similar data per day, after experimenting a bit, this is the fastest I could find for my scenario

```
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM stats
GROUP BY record_date DIV 1000000;
```

If you want to have it per month, add additional zeroes (00)
I would not recommend this from "make the code readable" perspective, it might also break in different versions. But in our case this took less then half the time compared to some other more clearer queries that I tested.

This is a MySQL answer (as MySQL is tagged in the question) and well documented in the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-type-conversion.html

Comment: Why does this work? A quirk of MySQL. While fulfilling this query, it implicitly converts `2021-03-04 05:06:07` to the number 20,210,304,050,607. (Commas added for clarity).  `DIV 1,000,000` of that number yields the number 20,210,304, representing the day. It's probably best to avoid this particular quirk when handling other peoples' data.

Comment: Converting dates to numeric in MySQL is documented https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-type-conversion.html "Conversion of TIME and DATETIME values to numeric form (for example, by adding +0)" so not a quirk, however it does make the query less then clear.

Comment: It's a quirk in the sense that other dbms makes and models don't work this way.

Comment: Updated answer to make it clear that this is a feature of MySQL that is well documented, and it should not be expected to work with anything else. The question has MySQL in the title and is also tagged with mysql, so it was found and answered in that context.

Answer (score 0):

`.... group by to_char(date, 'YYYY')` --> 1989

`.... group by to_char(date,'MM')`     -->05

`.... group by to_char(date,'DD')`   --->23

`.... group by to_char(date,'MON')`  --->MAY

`.... group by to_char(date,'YY')`   --->89

Comment: This would be very very slow.

Answer (score 0):

In simpler terms, without ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY, you can write a query where you group data by one column but still display other columns in the result without needing to aggregate them. This can be more convenient for certain queries, but it's important to use this feature carefully to avoid unintended results. By default slq_mode is ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY in mysql server, so just make sure whenever you group data you cannot show data which doesn't match with the group by. i.e if you are grouping by `MONTH(TABLE.creation_date)` THEN you cannot select TABLE.creation_date you have to convert it to `SELECT MONTH(TABLE.creation_date)`

Example:

```
// ❌ WRONG
SELECT DATE(TABLE.creation_date) FROM TABLE GROUP BY MONTH(inv.creation_date); // groups data by month
//END OF WRONG QUERY

// ✅ CORRECT
SELECT MONTH(TABLE.creation_date) FROM TABLE GROUP BY MONTH(inv.creation_date);
//END OF CORRECT QUERY
```

Answer (score -1):

Or you can use group by clause like this,

```
//to get data by month and year do this ->
SELECT FORMAT(TIMESTAMP_COLUMN, 'MMMM yy') AS Month, COUNT(ID) FROM TABLE_NAME GROUP BY FORMAT(TIMESTAMP_COLUMN, 'MMMM yy')
```

if you want to fetch records by date then in group by change format to
'dd-mm-yy' or 'dd-MMMM-yyy'

Comment: MySql's FORMAT() does not format dates: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format

Comment: Sorry My bad, 

this is example for MSSQL, and My sql have function called DATE_FORMAT() you can use that,

For more understanding [visit this link](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/func_mysql_date_format.asp)

Comment: The question is not tagged SQL Server and your code does not work for MySql.