# date change in sql

Tags: mysql

hi I  have a date which is 2009-06-02 00:00:00.000 and i want to only group by month ..

how can change it ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to group by month, but have data that spans more than one year. In that case, I would do:

```
group by Year(MyDate), Month(MyDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
group by MONTH(record_date)
```

see this question for more information :

[MySQL Query GROUP BY day / month / year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508791/mysql-query-group-by-day-month-year)

Comment: Note that this'll require the MONTH() function to be executed against every row in the table every time it's requested...

Comment: ops sorry month and year without the day !!

Comment: i add a link to similar question that support this

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ... GROUP BY MONTH(datecolumn)
```