# How to filter records from date in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

In my database, there is a field called birthday(date) and I want to retrieve records that their birth month and birth day is equal to the current month and the day. Is there a way to write a query for this? Or I just have to do it by retrieving all of the records and find the matching records after by using another program? Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This might also work: (NOTE that I am not sure if you mean day within a Month or day within a week)?

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE MONTH(birthday) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)
AND DAY(birthday) = DAY(CURRENT_DATE)    --assuming day within a month
```

Comment: Also checkout this http://stackoverflow.com/q/508791/247184 - its got some pointers.

Answer (score 5):

```
select * from table
where date_format(birthday, '%m%d')=date_format(current_date, '%m%d');
```

*The above query would not make use of mysql index*

Comment: %y => Wouldn't it be %d instead ? here you are comparing year and month where day & month is asked.