# Get statistics by day - datetime column - mysql/php

Tags: php, mysql, statistics

I have an issue that I can't solve by myself. The best thing would be if it's possible to do it directly from mysql but if not, calculating from php is also good.

I have a table that has 3 columns: id, time, value

Now the time value is datetime (example: 2012-11-03 00:13:12)

I want to create statistics from the last 7 days. Let's say I have 7 rows and today is 2012-12-20.

Here are the rows:
datetime                   value
2012-12-20 00:12:12      2
2012-12-20 04:06:15      4
2012-12-20 03:12:14      5
2012-12-18 03:12:14      7
2012-12-16 12:12:14      3
2012-12-16 14:23:34      2
2012-12-15 14:23:34      9

If I want to get the last 7 days report, it would be this:

> 2012-12-14 -> value =0
>   2012-12-15 -> value =9
>
> 2012-12-16 -> value =5
>
> 2012-12-17 -> value =0
>
> 2012-12-18 -> value =7
>   2012-12-19 -> value =0
>
> 2012-12-20 -> value =11

Currently I have this (extract last 7 day records):

```
$date=date("Y-m-d");
$date=date ("Y-m-d", strtotime ( '-7 day' . $date ) );  
$qry="select value,date from mytable where date>'$date'";
$res=mysql_query($qry) or die("Couldn't select Information : ".mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
        echo $row["value"];
    }
```

I hope somebody can help with advice.
 Thanks in advance!
 Vlad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be relatively easy to solve using just MySQL. This is very similar to this question: [MySQL Query GROUP BY day / month / year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508791/mysql-query-group-by-day-month-year)

You need to change your query so it gets all the records for a given week.

```
SELECT DAY(date) , SUM(value)
FROM mytable
WHERE WEEK(date) = WEEK(NOW())
GROUP BY DAY(date)
```

Its also very easy to change how you group the numbers, for example by month using `GROUP BY MONTH(date)`. You could also make the MySQL display the day name as a field by doing `SELECT DAYNAME(date)` For more details on what functions are available check out the [MySQL User Guide on Date and Time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for! I am using DATE_FORMAT(date,'format') because I want to also get the year/month, but it's perfect!