# MySQL count and group by day

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following structure

```
ID    DATE(DATETIME)         TID
1     2012-04-01 23:23:23    8882
```

I'm trying to count the amount of rows and group them by each day of the month that matches TID = 8882

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Query GROUP BY day / month / year](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508791/mysql-query-group-by-day-month-year)

Comment: Have u tried anything? or u r just waiting for whole code? and what do u mean by group them by each day? u mean group by date?

Comment: when you say "group by day" ... do you mean all items within a single date ? or you want to group items that fall into the same day of the month of different months (e.g. 1 Jan and 1 Feb, and 1 March together) ?

Answer (score 21):

You can group using the [DAY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_day) function:

```
SELECT DAY(Date), COUNT(*)
FROM table
WHERE TID = 8882
GROUP BY DAY(Date)
```

Comment: this helped me a lot I was missing the Day() rapper. I actually needed date(), but your answer led me to my solution. +1

Answer (score 10):

Not sure exactly what you mean by day of the month -- do you want to group the 1st of Feb with the 1st of March? Or do you just mean date? Assuming the latter, how about this:

```
SELECT DATE(date) as d,count(ID) from TABLENAME where TID=8882 GROUP by d;
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(id), DAY(dat), MONTH(dat), YEAR(dat) 
FROM table
WHERE TID=8882
GROUP BY YEAR(dat), MONTH(dat), DAY(dat);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT DAY(date) AS `DAY`,  COUNT(1) AS `COUNT` FROM
table1 
    WHERE TID = 8882
GROUP BY DAY(date)
```

What about [MySQL Query GROUP BY day / month / year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508791/mysql-query-group-by-day-month-year)

Answer (score 3):

count for every date:

```
SELECT date(created_at), COUNT(*)
FROM message_requests
GROUP BY date(created_at)
```