# Generate result by day

Tags: php, mysql, count

I am working on `PHP` and `MySQL`, I want to count result that are generated today and yesterday.

Here is screenshot of my `phpmyadmin` and table is `results`. In `date_generate` column I have used `TIMESTAMP`

[image: table]

I have this query which count total results

```php
<?php

   $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `results`");
   $count = $query->rowCount();
   echo $count;
```

Comment: Here's a hint: start with using a `WHERE` clause. You should show some minimum effort before asking for help.

Comment: yes i trying form yesterday, but still problem, can u post query for this

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please do some research before asking new questions. This one has been answered many times already. Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395444/mysql-count-and-group-by-day

Comment: yes i have searched as well but from my query its showing output result 1,
can you post query for me

Comment: I wish there was a flag for "Learn SQL first"

Comment: Problem solved now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your query :

```
 $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `results` where date_generate BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 day) AND CURDATE()");
$query->execute(); 
echo $count = $query->rowCount();
```

Comment: Check the updated answer, and use the $count variable. echo $query->execute(); will always return 1 or 0  as its return type will always be BOOL (true or false)

Comment: if you feel this is correct, plz tick the check button

Comment: i'm really sorry but i have not repu that i can vote :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `group by` to get the records created based on date_genrate. So, your query will be something like
Considering `date_generate` as timestammp

```
SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(date_generate)) AS date_g, COUNT(id) AS NumPosts
 FROM   results
 WHERE date_generate BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 day) AND CURDATE()
 GROUP BY date_g
 ORDER BY date_g
```

Comment: i tried this but still this showing output is 1 
here is query i tried
'<?php $query = $db->query("SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(date_generate)) AS date_g, COUNT(id) AS NumPosts
 FROM   results
 WHERE date_generate BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 day) AND CURDATE()
 GROUP BY date_g
 ORDER BY date_g
"); 
echo $query->execute(); ?> '

Comment: get row_count.... execute will return only query executed successfully or not....try running query directly in phpmyadmin and see result...