# Is it possible to return the total count of distinct ip_address for every day between a range?

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table,

For simplicity's sake assume the following table was used

```
CREATE TABLE requests(
    id INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
    ipaddress VARCHAR(30) NULL,
    datetime DATETIME NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Is it possible to return a result set for the count of distinct ip addresses in a 24 hour period, every day between now and and 180 days ago?

```
datetime               ipaddress
2012-10-25 00:00:00    30
2012-10-24 00:00:00    28
2012-10-24 00:00:00    22
2012-10-23 00:00:00    27
...                    ...
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508791/mysql-query-group-by-day-month-year  and count distinct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
select DATE(`datetime`),count(distinct ipaddress) as ipaddress
from requests
where datediff(NOW(),datetime)<=180
group by DATE(`datetime`)
```

Comment: Just a question, shouldn't you use GETDATE() - instead on NOW()?

Comment: @NewAmbition: GETDATE() is a sql server equivalent for NOW() in mysql. The question is tagged with mysql

Answer (score 0):

```
  select count(Distinct ipaddress  ) as total from 
 requests where date(datetime)> date_sub(date(datetime),interval 2 day)  
 group by ipaddress
```