# MYSQL group by day, week and month with php timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL Query GROUP BY day / month / year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508791/mysql-query-group-by-day-month-year)

I have php timestamps (e.g. 1307362819) stored in a column in my database. I want to group count(*) in days, weeks and months the data.

For example I want to find out how many entries there are per day, per week, and per month etc.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: have you tried something ?

Comment: MONTH(  `timeStamp` )  returns NULL

Answer (score 4):

You can subtract day, week and month value from a timestamp, and group the subtracted values.

grouping by day value:

```
select count(*) from table group by from_unixtime(timeStampColumn, '%Y%m%d')
```

grouping by week value:

```
select count(*) from table group by from_unixtime(timeStampColumn, '%Y%m%u')
```

grouping by monthvalue:

```
select count(*) from table group by from_unixtime(timeStampColumn, '%Y%m')
```

For more information, have a look at this page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use these: <>

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourTable WHERE yourTimestampField > someTimestampAWeekPast;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourTable WHERE yourTimestampField > someTimestampADayPast;
```

Use the mysql date/time functions http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html to calculate the desired date in the past.
Use UNIX_TIMESTAMP if you stored them as int or string or whatever.

Comment: i want to for example do: dec 16 X posts, dec 15 x posts (and do this for the past 15 days no matter what today is), also i want to do the same with weeks and months to get a picture of how many posts are made.

Comment: MONTH(  `timeStamp` )  returns NULL

Answer (score 0):

here a good exemple for you

[to group by week](http://sqlize.com/)

EDIT:

try this

```
          select
id_user,
year(time) as AYear, week(time) as AWeek, day(time) as Aday ,
count(week(time)) as TotalPerWeek , count(day(time)) as TotalPerDay ,
count(year(time)) as TotalPerYear
from yourtable
where id_user = 16             //// the user u want to check
group by id_user, AYear, AWeek , Aday
order by AYear, AWeek , Aday
```

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT MONTH( FROM_UNIXTIME(  `timeStamp` ) ) , COUNT(  `id` ) 
FROM  `discusComments` 
GROUP BY MONTH( FROM_UNIXTIME(  `timeStamp` ) )
```

Comment: Explain **why** that could solve the problem.