# group by unique month per year, not just month

Tags: php, mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL Query GROUP BY day / month / year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508791/mysql-query-group-by-day-month-year)

I have the following mysql:

```
SELECT MONTH( FROM_UNIXTIME(  `timeStamp` ) ) as month , COUNT(  `id` )  as count
FROM  `discusComments` 
GROUP BY MONTH( FROM_UNIXTIME(  `timeStamp` ) ) 
ORDER BY  MONTH( FROM_UNIXTIME(  `timeStamp` ) ) ASC 
LIMIT 15
```

It gets the amount of entries made per month in the past 15 months. I was wondering WHY it only displayed the past 12 months ... then I realised the count was an aggregate of all years and not unique per month year. So the value for december could be 2012 and 2011 together.

I donÄt want this. I want to get the past 15 months and the amount of entries made for UNIQUE month year, e.g. december 2012, november 2012 etc.

Comment: month returns 1-12 inclusive

Comment: I dont know how to make it so that it groups by "month year" and not just "month" or "year"

Answer (score 1):

Add year to your `SELECT` column list and add the alias to `GROUP BY` too.

```
SELECT YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(`timestamp`))  AS year, 
       MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(`timestamp`)) AS month, 
       COUNT(`id`)                       AS count 
FROM   `discuscomments` 
GROUP  BY year, 
          month 
ORDER  BY year,
          month
LIMIT  15
```

Answer (score 1):

The most straight forward idea I have on this is normally to change the format of the date value to a unique and speaking string, like 2012-12 for December 2012 and 2011-10 for October 2011 etc.

A function you can use for that is [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
 DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(timeStamp), '%Y-%m')
```

These strings are then easily sortable, e.g. ASC:

```
2011-10
2011-11
2011-12
...
2012-10
2012-11
2012-12
```

Example SQL query:

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(timeStamp), '%Y-%m') as month, 
  COUNT(id) as count
FROM  discusComments
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month ASC 
LIMIT 15
```

Comment: But this adds complexity when later you have to split that `month`  column.

Comment: Yes, it's just some kind of "do-it-yourself"/"help-yourself" solution that is applicable even on low-level systems. Your answer is much nicer adopting to SQL itself. Also just seeing [MySQL Query GROUP BY day / month / year](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508791/mysql-query-group-by-day-month-year)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
months_between(to_date ('2009/05/15', 'yyyy/mm/dd'), 
                     to_date ('2009/04/16', 'yyyy/mm/dd'))
```

Comment: Hey you should probably elaborate as to why your solution would work