# How to count data within date intervals

Tags: sql, count, intervals

I want to make a graph chart from [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) that count how much products have been sold from past 12 months.

For example:
today is Jan, 7th

assume my sql table like this:

```
DATE           SOLD
feb-6           5
feb-8           7
mar-10          15
mar-30          1
apr-1           6
and so on..
```

so the sql must produce like this:
feb = 12, mar = 16, apr = .... and so on until this month. anybody can help me? coz i have no idea how to write the correct sql code.

this is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    options = {
    chart: {renderTo: 'chart', type: 'line', marginRight: 130, marginBottom: 25},
    credits: {enabled: false},
    title: {text: 'Sales Performance', x: -20},
    xAxis: {categories: [{}]},
    yAxis: {title: {text: 'sold'}, plotLines: [{value: 0,width: 1,color: '#808080'}]},
    legend: {layout: 'vertical', align: 'right', verticalAlign: 'top', x: -10, y: 100, borderWidth: 0},
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            var s = '<b>'+ this.x +'</b>';
            $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
                s += '<br/>'+point.series.name+': '+point.y;
            });
            return s;
        },
        shared: true
    },
    series: [{},{}]
};
$.ajax({
    url: "generate_graph",
    data: 'date='+dateText,
    type: 'post',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        options.xAxis.categories = data.categories;
            options.series[0].name = data.name;
            options.series[0].data = data.value;
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);          
    }
    });
})
```

Comment: do you need sql query to do it or need to do it in javascript? how are you loading data using just javascript?

Comment: I need sql query to be generated as json. I got the php from here http://blueflame-software.com/blog/pass-date-parameter-to-highcharts-line-chart/ but I need to edit the sql code to suit my needs

Comment: you may whant to check this : [MySQL Query GROUP BY day / month / year][1]

Answer [GROUP BY YEAR(record_date), MONTH(record_date)][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508791/mysql-query-group-by-day-month-year
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/508806/3148693

Comment: how are you storing Date in the table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I m just answering the sql query:

```
select
  month(solddate), 
  sum(sold)
from 
  selling
where solddate between date_sub(now(), interval 1 year) and now()
group by month(solddate);
```

see **[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/661f0/1)**

Answer (score 1):

you may whant to check this : [MySQL Query GROUP BY day / month / year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508791/mysql-query-group-by-day-month-year)

[Answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/508806/3148693)

```
GROUP BY YEAR(record_date), MONTH(record_date)
```