# PHP MySQL: count views per month for jQuery charts

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, chart.js

i work with `jQuery` chart.js for show view counter by `month` using `PHP` and `MySql`. I insert/Put each views page to MySql like this :

```
| id |     ip        |   page   | date(timestamp) |
|  1 | 138.86.20.20  | test.php |   1375710823    |
|  2 | 100.86.123.10 | test.php |   1380206563    |
```

for chart.js :

```
var data = {
    labels: ["january","February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [{
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: [150,59, 90, 81, 56, 55, 40]
    }, {
        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        data: [20,48, 40, 59, 500, 127, 100]
    }]
}

var options = {animation :true};

//Get the context of the canvas element we want to select
var c = $('#daily-chart');
var ct = c.get(0).getContext('2d');
var ctx = document.getElementById("daily-chart").getContext("2d");


//Run function when window resizes
$(window).resize(respondCanvas);

function respondCanvas() {
    c.attr('width', jQuery("#daily").width());
    c.attr('height', jQuery("#daily").height());
    //Call a function to redraw other content (texts, images etc)
    myNewChart = new Chart(ct).Bar(data, options);
}

//Initial call 
respondCanvas();
```

Now, I need to count views by/per month for chart.js data ouput using json format.

`[150,59, 90, 81, 56, 55, 40,12,54,65,365,2]` for 12 month strat @january.

How to crate this?!

NOTE: charts datasets have two color : 1- unique user 2- all user

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508791/mysql-query-group-by-day-month-year

Answer (score 1):

You could use a query to group the visits by month:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), MONTH(date(timestamp)), YEAR(date(timestamp))
FROM table 
GROUP BY MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(date(timestamp)), YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(date(timestamp))
```

Which will return the number of visits, with the year and month they correspond to.

**\EDIT\**

To loop through and print each month's value, use a mysqli_query and `WHILE` in PHP:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "THE QUERY ABOVE ^^");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query {
echo $row['date(timestamp)'].",";
}
```

Comment: Ok, But i need to show count for each month with json output:  `[150,59, 90, 81, 56, 55, 40,12,54,65,365,2]`

Comment: Use a mysqli_query and WHILE loop in PHP to loop through the rows returned by the query, then echo them into your script. Check my edit to see what I mean.