# How to group values by timestamp day in php

Tags: php

I have a table with all my invoices, where I save the date as a TIME STAMP and the total value of the invoice.

I want to make a graphic based on the sales that needs the day and the value.
But in the table there are more totals per day, so I made the query to get the rows from the current month and I get an output something like :

> Date: 1403739780 / Value : 2167

Now I want to know how to group the values in one that are from the same day ( in PHP ) but I don't know any simple way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Query GROUP BY day / month / year](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508791/mysql-query-group-by-day-month-year)

Comment: I made the query how to get the results by current month now I have many rows returned and need a way to sort them in an array or something by Day and total value of that day .... in PHP not mysql

Comment: Then why does the question have a MySQL tag?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the timestamp as the key of the array:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "database");
$result = array();
$sql = "SELECT ...";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $day = date("Ymd", $row["timestamp"]);
    $result[$day] += $row["value"];
}
```