# Find total number of tickets per day within a specific date range

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm, trying to write a query that will allow me to do the following:

"Find total number of open and closed tickets per day, within a specific date range".

Here's what I got so far

```
SELECT
COUNT(tikcet_id) as totalTickets, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN ticket_status = 'Complete' 
      THEN 1 
      ELSE NULL END) as closedTickets,
DATE(ticket_date)
FROM tickets 
WHERE (DATE(ticket_date) BETWEEN DATE('2014-07-18') AND DATE('2014-07-30'))
GROUP BY ticket_date
```

This is the results I'm getting, it counts the tickets fine, it just doesn't group them the way I want.

```
TotalTickets| ClosedTickets| ticket_date
           1|             0| 2014-07-21 10:00:00
           1|             0| 2014-07-21 10:21:21
           0|             1| 2014-07-21 11:45:12
           0|             1| 2014-07-22 09:21:24
           0|             1| 2014-07-22 09:43:23
```

I would like to have them grouped by day, so for example I should be able to see something like that:

```
TotalTickets| ClosedTickets| ticket_date
           2|             1| 2014-07-21
           2|             0| 2014-07-22
```

Comment: Here is what you're looking for : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508791/mysql-query-group-by-day-month-year

Comment: What happens when you use this grouping command `GROUP BY DATE(ticket_date)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make this

```
GROUP BY DATE(ticket_date)
```

instead of

```
GROUP BY ticket_date
```

You're doing it right in the `SELECT` clause already.

And btw, a shorter way of writing this

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN ticket_status = 'Complete' 
      THEN 1 
      ELSE NULL END) as closedTickets,
```

is

```
SUM(ticket_status = 'Complete') as closedTickets,
```

boolean expressions evaluate to `true` or `false`, `1` or `0`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have one more question, is there a way to show days that have no tickets at all? I'm currently getting results only for days which have records.

Comment: You can't select what isn't there. Either solve it on application level, or you create a table just containing dates and left join it.