# select records from a table for each different date in single iteration of SQL query

Tags: sql, for-loop, teradata

Sorry for the vague Problem statement, maybe I could not frame it the right way hence couldn't get much help from the internet.

My basic intent is to select two columns from a table, where the table has been partitioned based on dates, and has huge number of records.

The intent is to select records for each date from jan 1 to nov 30, can't do it using date between statement, I need to input each date separately in the iteration in for loop.

Can anyone help writing a dummy sql query on this?

Thanks,

Comment: as a pseudocode, I'd want for (date in DATES)SELECT col1,col2 from TABLE where datecol is date. Thanks!

Comment: I know this, but datatable is soo huge! I have to access just one partition for a query, it is a query optimization problem basically.

Comment: I dont think that you will win anything by using a forloop over the  "GROUP BY" as the sqldatabase still needs to look throw the hole table.

Comment: Why do you need to run one query for every date? Do you get a spool error when you run a single query? Do you need to process all rows for a given date or just some?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use any scripting language to iterate over each day to achieve.
below is a sample (untested code)

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect(DSN='dsnname',autocommit=True,ansi=True)
cur = conn.cursor()
sql = "INSERT INTO tgt_table SELECT col1,col2 FROM src_table WHERE partitioned_date_column = date '2014-01-01' + INTERVAL '%d' DAY"

for i in range(1,30):
    cur.execute(sql % i)
```

Comment: Thanks man , I dont know who you are, but you have been an immense help, You made my day, Thanks a ton !

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how your tables look like, but have you tryed something like this:

"`WHERE {yourRow} > X GROUP BY date`"

[MySQL Query GROUP BY day / month / year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508791/mysql-query-group-by-day-month-year)

Hope this can help you :-)

`SELECT col1, col2 FROM {table} WHERE datecol between '2000-01-01'
and
    DATE_ADD('2000-01-31',INTERVAL 1 DAY)`

OR

```
SELECT col1, col2, FROM {table} GROUP BY DAY(datecol)
```

Comment: I know this, but datatable is soo huge! I have to access just one partition for a query, it is a query optimization problem basically.

Comment: Ok,so this interval 1 day, does it only access one partition of the datatable, As in, it shouldnt be spanning a query over few datapartitions.

Comment: I have not read all the documentation on this subject, but I would assume that the first example is the fastest as it first look at the date, and if date is out of range then break, else it would select.

I think you will need to test for yourself of what is the fastest way to do it. (WHERE vs GROUP BY) please let me know what your benchmarks are saying.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use oracle, this dummy select should give you the list of dates to join

```
select to_date('01.01.2014','dd.mm.yyyy') + level - 1
from dual
connect by level -1 <= to_date('30.11.2014','dd.mm.yyyy') - to_date('01.01.2014','dd.mm.yyyy')
```

Comment: Very nice, but then for each such date i want the records eg tuple col1,col2,datecol from the table, where datecol is that date in the iterator. I have to write basically sql query on teradata