# Group by month of datetime

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

Can I group by month in a MySQL `DATETIME` field or do I have to create separate fields with just the month and the year?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Query GROUP BY day / month / year](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508791/mysql-query-group-by-day-month-year)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can like this

```
select month(datetime_field)
from your_table
group by month(datetime_field)
```