# Selecting rows of data into months

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have rows of data in a database that have a `DATETIME` called date on. There is another column called points.

I need to count all the points for each month and return a list of total points for each month in order of month with most points down.

I'm not really sure where to start when it comes to selecting rows by month?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Query GROUP BY day / month / year](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508791/mysql-query-group-by-day-month-year)

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the month and year from the date using [`monthname`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname) (or [`month`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month)) and [`year`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year), respectively, and group by them:

```
SELECT   YEAR(`date`), MONTHNAME(`date`), SUM(`points`)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY YEAR(`date`), MONTHNAME(`date`)
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

Note that if your table represents a single year, or you want to calculate a multi-year total, you should omit the year expression from the `select` list and the `group by` clause.

Comment: I was up for helping when opening this question. Now you helped me hah. Monthname will seriously be useful for me. Upped.