# MySQL COUNT by Day of Week

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, select, group-by

Using a variation of the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508791/mysql-query-group-by-day-month-year) using Group By, I'm trying to do a count of how many records occurred on each day of the week and display the count by the day of the week.  I am getting a syntax error even though I've tried to also include `DATE(ScheduleDateExact,%Y-%m-%d)`.

What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT COUNT(WorkOrderNum)
FROM ScheduleRequest
GROUP BY DAYOFWEEK (DATE(ScheduleDateExact)) FROM ScheduleRequest
```

Comment: First, that last FROM ScheduleRequest in the query. Remove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a redundant `from` clause after the `group by` clause. Get rid of it, and you should be fine. I recommend, however, you add the day-of-week extraction to the `select` list too, so you can easily understand the results you're getting:

```
SELECT   DAYOFWEEK(DATE(ScheduleDateExact)), COUNT(WorkOrderNum)
FROM     ScheduleRequest
GROUP BY DAYOFWEEK(DATE(ScheduleDateExact))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Mureinik!