# How to delete duplicate date

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have a project in Laravel. I want returned date with table "transmits" with column "created_at". This column is type `datetime`.

[image]

When I returned date on my site I have this:

> Select date: 2016-08-24 2016-08-24 2016-08-24 2016-08-24 2016-08-25
>   2016-08-25

I want the date to be displayed individually. Like this:

> Select date: 2016-08-24 2016-08-25

My code:

```
print $dayDate = (Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $days->created_at)->format('Y-m-d'));
```

I can't using `groupBy` in query to databse, because `created_at` column is the date and hour. The hour differ from each other, therefore I can not use a `groupBy`. I can't also use `array_unique()`, because variable `$dayDate` returned this when i using `var_dump`:

> string(10) "2016-08-24" string(10) "2016-08-24" string(10)
>   "2016-08-24" string(10) "2016-08-24" string(10) "2016-08-25"
>   string(10) "2016-08-25"

**Each date is a separate table. I do not know how I can combine them into a single table.**

***Edit:***
In file view:

```
@foreach($day as $days)
   <?php 
   $dayDate = (Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $days->created_at)->format('Y-m-d'));
   var_dump ($dayDate);

   ?>
@endforeach
```

And in file controller:

```
$day = transmit::select('created_at')->groupBy('created_at')->get();
```

My post is not duplicate this post [MySQL Query GROUP BY day / month / year][2]

[2]: [MySQL Query GROUP BY day / month / year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508791/mysql-query-group-by-day-month-year), because in my column `created_at` is date, hour, munte and secon, therefore I can not use the groupBy.

Comment: Show us the query you are asking for help with

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508791/mysql-query-group-by-day-month-year

Comment: @u_mulder Are you going to dup this with that

Comment: @RiggsFolly not quite sure

Comment: @RiggsFolly I updated my post

Comment: Dont know how to do it in Laravel/Carbon but I think you are asking for `SELECT DATE(created_at) ` query syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following expression

```
$day = transmit::selectRaw('date(created_at) as created_date')->groupBy('created_date')->get();
```

One drawback is mysql can't use index on the field created_at so it will slow down the query.

Answer (score 0):

If you have dates as string, you can:

```
<?php
$old_dates = "2016-08-24 2016-08-24 2016-08-24 2016-08-24 2016-08-25 2016-08-25";
$new_dates = implode(" ", array_unique(explode(" ", $old_dates)));
echo $new_dates;
```

Comment: So, $dayDate is an array?

Comment: Yes it is array, but $dayDate is separated array, look: string(10) "2016-08-24" string(10) "2016-08-24" string(10) "2016-08-24" string(10) "2016-08-24" string(10) "2016-08-25" string(10) "2016-08-25"

Comment: What does print_r($dayDate) returns?

Comment: print_r returned this: 2016-08-24 2016-08-24 2016-08-24 2016-08-24 2016-08-25 2016-08-25

Comment: I cant understand $daydate is a string or array. What do you mean by "separated array"? If it is array then why print_r doesn't return array{} ?