# How to count distinct group by field SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this data in my database :

```
nama             tanggal     
ADIESTY.SW       2017-03-01  
ADIESTY.SW       2017-03-01  
ADIESTY.SW       2017-03-02  
ADIESTY.SW       2017-03-02  
ADIESTY.SW       2017-03-03  
ADIESTY.SW       2017-03-03  
ADIESTY.SW       2017-03-05  
ADIESTY.SW       2017-03-05  
ALFRED APDIAN    2017-03-01  
ALFRED APDIAN    2017-03-01  
ALFRED APDIAN    2017-03-02  
ALFRED APDIAN    2017-03-02  
ARI PUTRA        2017-03-01  
ARI PUTRA        2017-03-01  
ARI PUTRA        2017-03-02  
ARI PUTRA        2017-03-02  
ARI PUTRA        2017-03-03  
ARI PUTRA        2017-03-03
```

How do I count by distinct date (tanggal)? So the result I want is:

```
    nama         tanggal
ADIESTY.SW        4
ALFRED APDIAN     2
ARI PUTRA         3
```

Comment: The double quotes aren't actually there in your data and expected output, are they?

Comment: Hint: Google "group by"

Comment: It's simple aggregation - `select name, count(*) from t group by name`

Comment: that only because copy to clipboard by SQLyog

Comment: @AkbarTriNanda - I changed your question to be specific to what you wanted. In future, please give exact data and sample output based on that. Also show your effort/problem which you are not able to resolve by yourself. Cheers!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Query GROUP BY day / month / year](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508791/mysql-query-group-by-day-month-year)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this

```
select nama,count(distinct tanggal) from your_table
group by nama;
```

http://rextester.com/ZOZQK78377

Answer (score 1):

When you post the question specify the type of database used (Oracle,MySQL,..)

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 0):

To get that data the query should be

```
SELECT `name`, COUNT(*) as `count`
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `name`
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
         select name,count(name) as count from (
  select 'ADIESTY.SW' as Name,'2017-03-01' as date union
  select 'ADIESTY.SW' as Name,'2017-03-02'as date union
  select 'ADIESTY.SW' as Name,'2017-03-03'as date union
  select 'ADIESTY.SW' as Name,'2017-03-05'as date union
  select 'ALFRED APDIAN'as Name,'2017-03-01'as date union
  select 'ALFRED APDIAN' as Name,'2017-03-02'as date union
  select 'ARI PUTRA' as Name, '2017-03-01'as date union
  select 'ARI PUTRA'  as Name,'2017-03-02'as date union
  select 'ARI PUTRA'  as Name, '2017-03-03'as date
  )t
  group by name
```