# How to find specific year with show all the month

Tags: php, laravel, date

1,I can get my current year income but don't know how to show all monthly income of current year.

2, if I want to create **$selectYear** as **pick** one of the random year then show the specific year monthly income of **$selectYear** just like question 1.

What I have try only the current/select year income but show monthly income of year, i still stuck there.

this my controller

```
public function index(){
  $selectYear= 2017;
    $this->getYearRevenue($selectYear);
    //customPickYearRevenue is for totalIncome of $selectYear
    $customPickYearRevenue = $this->getYearRevenue($selectYear);
}

private function getYearRevenue($selectYear){
    $yearPickRevenue = Order::whereYear('created_at', '=', $selectYear)
    ->where('order_status', 'Accepted')
    ->sum('amount');

    return $yearPickRevenue;
  }
```

I want to show month with amount(revenue of year)

sorry about hard code **$selectYear**

Comment: it is not clear what you wish ...what do you mean with 'all month'. Do you wish to get specific mount|year revenue or all months of a specific year?

Comment: I didn't get what you mean exactly. Please provide more information about what you wish

Comment: i have edit the information ,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Query GROUP BY day / month / year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508791/mysql-query-group-by-day-month-year)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
private function getRevenue($selectYear, $selectMonth){
        return Order::whereYear('created_at', '=', $selectYear)
            ->whereMonth('created_at', '=', $selectMonth)
            ->where('order_status', 'Accepted')
            ->sum('amount');
    }
```

And then you can use a loop to get the revenue for each month:

```
$year = 20019;
$months = ['1', '2', '3',];
$revenues = [];

foreach($months as $month){
     array_push($revenues, getRevenue($year, $month);
}
```