# SQL - Select all customers from month

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to make a sql for statistic over customers.
I would like to print all customers from may, april, juni, july and so on.
Example:

- In jan i have 20 new customers
- In feb i have 5 new customers
- In Mar i have 10 new customers
- ..... and so on

My database look like

```
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `displayName` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `firstname` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `lastname` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `phoneNo` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `website` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `industry_Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `date` date NOT NULL,
```

Comment: What do you mean by "new customer"?  What does your table have to do with "customers"?

Comment: Im justing make a small CRM. And would like to see how many customers im making each month. For statistics. So I can in 2 years look back at my business and see how it goes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL Query GROUP BY day / month / year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508791/mysql-query-group-by-day-month-year)

Comment: "My database look like" -- Unless you somehow managed to have free floating columns, you rather mean "table" not "database"....

Comment: @stickybit Yeah ofcorse :D haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you just want aggregation?

```
select date_format(c.date, '%Y-%m') mon, count(*) cnt
from customers c
group by date_format(c.date, '%Y-%m')
```

Comment: Exactly! Thank u so much! :)