# Mysql - Calculate Times per month - organise result

Tags: mysql

I'm extracting data from sql by the following SQL Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(transics_bco.arab))) AS arab,
  transics_bco.plate
FROM transics_bco
WHERE transics_bco.extdate BETWEEN '2019-12-01' AND '2019-12-31'
GROUP BY transics_bco.plate
```

This gives me the following result:

```
-----------------------
| ARAB      | Plate   |
-----------------------
| 178:44:43 | 1ABC123 |
| 156:23:44 | 1DEF456 |
-----------------------
```

Is it possible to get the result shown as this;

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
| Plate   | December 19 | January 20 | February 20 | March 20 |
--------------------------------------------------------------- 
| 1ABC123 | 178:44:43   | 120:34:56  | ...         | ...      |
| 1DEF456 | 156:23:44   | 102:34:54  | ...         | ...      |
| 1GHI789 | 111:22:33   | 156:35:35  | ...         | ...      |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

SQL Sample: `transics_bco`

```
----------------------------------------
| id | plate   | arab     | extdate    |
----------------------------------------
| 1  | 1ABC123 | 00:14:23 | 2019-12-01 |
| 2  | 1ABC123 | 00:10:20 | 2019-12-03 |
| 3  | 1ABC123 | 00:45:06 | 2019-12-07 |
| 4  | 1ABC123 | 00:54:45 | 2020-01-02 |
| 5  | 1ABC123 | 00:26:10 | 2020-01-03 |
| 6  | 1ABC123 | 00:43:28 | 2020-01-04 |
----------------------------------------
```

Would greatly appreciate pointers in the good direction

---

Adding db describe as requested in the comments;

-
Adding describe of Transics_bco as requested in the comments

```
===================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
|                      Field                       |                       Type                       |                       Null                       |                       Key                        |                     Default                      |                      Extra                       |
===================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
|                        id                        |                     int(11)                      |                        NO                        |                       PRI                        |                       null                       |                  auto_increment                  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                      plate                       |                   varchar(255)                   |                        NO                        |                                                  |                       null                       |                                                  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                       arab                       |                       time                       |                        NO                        |                                                  |                     00:00:00                     |                                                  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                     extdate                      |                       date                       |                        NO                        |                                                  |                       null                       |                                                  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: It might be helpful to provide the schema of both tables.  Run `describe transics_soap;` and `describe transics_bco;`.

Comment: Hello Psyklopz, I've added both in the request above

Comment: @psyklopz: suppressed the soap db, wasn't really necessary. 
Added describe above

Comment: It might not exactly be what you are looking for, but I would consider grouping by plate, MONTH(), and YEAR().  It would put different months in different rows, (not columns, as asked) but it keeps everything contained in a single query.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/508806/1017107

Comment: Otherwise, I think the only way to accomplish what you are doing is with a UNION query.  That's something I've always seem as an anti-pattern, and so I've avoided.  I don't know enough about UNIONs to provide an answer.

Comment: If I count it correctly, the time difference between `| 1  | 1ABC123 | 00:14:23 | 2019-12-01 |` and  `| 3  | 1ABC123 | 00:45:06 | 2019-12-07 |` is actually `144:30:43` but your result return `178:44:43` .. it doesn't match with your example data given.. any clarification on that or it's just not complete? If so, please give us the full example that will return  `178:44:43` result. You should just make sure the result and example data provided are a match.. otherwise it will be confusing.. thanks

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  plate,
  december19,
  january20,
  february20,
  march20 
FROM
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT
      a.plate,
      (
        CASE
          WHEN
            Month(a.extdate) = 12 
            AND Year(a.extdate) = 2019 
          THEN
            Sec_to_time(Sum(Time_to_sec(a.arab))) 
        END
      )
      AS 'December19', 
      (
        CASE
          WHEN
            Month(a.extdate) = 1 
            AND Year(a.extdate) = 2020 
          THEN
            a.arab 
        END
      )
      AS 'January20, (CASE WHEN MONTH(a.extDate)=2 AND YEAR(a.extDate)=2020 THEN SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(a.arab))) END) AS 'february20', (CASE WHEN MONTH(a.extDate)=3 AND YEAR(a.extDate)=2020 THEN SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(a.arab))) END) AS 'march20', FROM transics_bco a WHERE transics_bco.extdate BETWEEN '2019-12-01' AND '2019-12-31' 
    GROUP BY
      transics_bco.plate
  )
  T 
GROUP BY
  T.plate;
```